# How to check total written size to USB thumb drives?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, drive-health

(Asking in general but I need the answer specifically for SanDisk drives)

Is there a way to see total written size to USB thumb drives? Just like Samsung-Magician's SSD health check, but for thumb/flash drives.

edit:
For example If you create a 2MB file, delete it and then create it again, the total written size will be 4MB but the free space will be {capacity}-2MB

Comment: You should consider specifying your operating system - maybe even in your title - to make your question as specific as possible.

Comment: I don't think there's a way unless it's one of those more expensive USB-bridged SATA thumb, which gives you some SMART data. (Extreme Pro or so; at least SanDisk used to do that for this line; not sure about these days.)

Comment: Use a third-party tool to monitor USB or *all* drives, such as CorSpaZio, https://corz.org/windows/software/corzspazio/#section-Download

Comment: @DrMoishePippik this shows current free/available space, but I'm talking about total written to the drive historically. For example If you create a 2MB file, delete it and then create it again, the total written size will be 4MB but the free space will be {capacity}-2MB

Comment: @J.Doe, that explanation belongs in the question, which you can edit. That said, I know of no way to do that. It would be useful if S.M.A.R.T. were implemented for USB flash drives, q.v. https://superuser.com/questions/1064119/usb-flash-drives-or-sd-cards-with-s-m-a-r-t

Answer (score 0):

SSD keeps track of these statistics itself and reports them which is how Samsung-Magician (or any other SMART tool) can show you this. AFAIK USB flash drives do not, and even if they did they don't report this data.